# change to text console using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, console

I'm connecting to target computer through SSH from command line. Target computer is running Gnome. I need to be able to tell the target computer to change its desktop to a fullscreen text console (like when you do `ctrl-alt-f2`). Running Gnome terminal fullscreen is not an option. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`chvt N` with `N` the number of the terminal (2 in your example). On Debian it's in the `kbd` package, I guess it should be the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know why I got downvotes, but I'm happy I asked because you and 200_success gave me a working solution! I'd also upvote but don't have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could run: `telinit 3` or `init 3` as root.

That will kill the graphical multiuser sessions and go into runlevel 3.

You don't mention the specific version of Linux, but for subsequent reboots, you want to default to runlevel 3 (instead of 5) in your `/etc/inittab`.

Comment: It seems to be distribution dependent. Neither init 3 nor telinit 3 stop xorg under debian 6 here. http://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel. Btw :Is there still any reason to use telinit nowadays except very old aix?

Comment: Remote computer is Ubuntu 11.10. telinit 3 or init 3 didn't work. Also there is no inittab, maybe because Ubuntu uses upstart?

Comment: Well, I guess Ubuntu is a valid OS :) Check out: http://askubuntu.com/questions/115469/cannot-change-runlevel-from-5-to-3

Answer (score 2):

Switch to virtual console 2 by executing [`chvt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chvt)`2`.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use `wmctrl`. It's a program which can mess with X windows. More information can be found [here](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/). Also: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl) article and [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl). This program can be installed on the target machine by running `apt-get install wmctrl`.

Comment: wmctrl seems to require correct Display parameter to be set and I don't want to use any X-forwarding. Am I missing something?

Comment: -1: wmctrl doesn't have anything to do with this (he wants to switch to a text console).